# How can I send email from the google-group email address?

Tags: gmail, google-groups

I created a google-group `mygroup` and asked to also create an email address for the group, `mygroup@googlegroups.com`. I want to email from my gmail account such that the sender address will be `mygroup@googlegroups.com`.

I went to Settings -> Accounts and Import -> Send mail as: -> Add another email address, added `mygroup@googlegroups.com`, checked "Treat as an alias" and clicked Next, but got a red error message saying "Please enter a valid email address".

How can I add this sender address?

Answer (score 4):

You can send email from the Google Groups address using its web page (see the steps below; they're harder to find after the recent UI changes), but you're correct that Gmail won't accept a group as a "Send mail as" address. (If that ever changes, it's probably better to [uncheck the "Treat as an alias" box](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1710338).)

To email from a Groups address:

1. Go to the Groups conversation list on the web, `https://groups.google.com/g/mygroup`.
2. Click the "+ New conversation" sausage near the upper left corner. (It doesn't look so much like a button.) --> That opens a `New conversation in mygroup` send-mail form.
3. In that send-mail form, click the down-arrow in the `From` section.
4. Pick `mygroup@googlegroups.com` in the list.
5. Compose and send.

Comment: I saw this form, but I do not see a "To" field in this form. This means that I can send a message only to the entire group - not to a specific person.

Comment: Erel Segal-Halevi as far as I know, it can only send to the entire group. You can check the Help Center, https://support.google.com/groups/?hl=en . Maybe your purpose requires another Gmail account. A good way to switch between accounts is to use a separate Chrome user profile for each one, or a separate browser.

Answer (score 0):

It will work now like you mentioned:

`I went to Settings -> Accounts and Import -> Send mail as: -> Add another email address, added mygroup@googlegroups.com, checked "Treat as an alias" and clicked Next, but got a red error message saying "Please enter a valid email address".`

But with one exception: you will have to UNcheck the "Treat as an alias" option. You will now be able to change your "From" field for each email you are sending.

You can also set the new email address as you standard "From", and/or "Reply-to" if needed/wanted ([source](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370#zippy=%2Cchange-default-from-address)):

- See all settings --> Accounts and import or Accounts tab.
- In the "Send mail as" section to the right of the address you want to use
- click "Make default".

The only thing I didn't yet manage to figure out is if we can also do this from inside the groups.google.com webUI

Comment: How di you manage to do that ? For me, no matter if I check/uncheck the "Treat as an alias" button it fails with the "Please enter a valid email address" error. I'm 100% sure the email is correct.

Comment: It works for me, but when sending a message from gmail, the recipient will receive the message as if it was sent by the group, however the message is not propagated to the group! Any clue?

Comment: Try using a plus address alias. If you email is jacob.smith@gmail.com, you can try using jacob.smith+alias@gmail.com with the custom reply-to email. It will work with or without the "Treat as an alias".